# C# How do I invoke a private overloaded method using System.Reflection when number of arguments are equal

Tags: c#, reflection, mstest

I have a class called `TicketManager`. This class has two private methods `private void Validate(Ticket ticket)` and an overload `private void Validate(TicketResponse ticketResponse)`.

When I use the `BindingFlags` without specifying the `Type[]` I get an Ambiguous Match Exception.

The following code is my unit test using MSTest.

```cs
//testing private validation method using reflection
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(TargetInvocationException))]
    public void Validate_TicketResponseIsInvalid_ReturnsValidationException()
    {
        //Arrange
        TicketManager ticketManager = new TicketManager(ticketRepository);
        Ticket t = new Ticket { AccountId = 1, Text = "How do I test a private method in C#?", TicketNumber = 5 };
        TicketResponse tr = new TicketResponse { Ticket = t, IsClientResponse = false, Date = DateTime.Now };

        //reflection
        MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(TicketManager).GetMethod("Validate", new Type[] { typeof(TicketResponse) });
        object[] parameters = {tr};
        //Act
        methodInfo.Invoke(ticketManager, parameters); //throws NullReferenceException

        //Assert
        //assertion happens using attribute added to method
    }
```

Comment: You're on the right track by using `.GetMethod` but you should make it absolutely clear that this question is not about the null reference exception, questions which mention this exception have a tendency to be closed as duplicates even when the question is actually about the behavior of an api method, that just happens to return null when you feed it parameters it doesn't handle.

Comment: But it is a clear sign of bad design if you have to call into private methods in order to test your class. You should refactor out the relevant bits so that you can access them without resorting to reflection. **OR** You shouldn't be testing this part, implementation details should be left as implementation details, you should only test the public contract, that it behaves correctly, not how it achieved that behavior. If the exact way it achieved it is part of the contract, it shouldn't (or doesn't have to) be private.

Comment: A slightly better way of structuring your code would be to have an internal class with the validation logic, it is much cleaner to use `InternalsVisibleTo` to allow access from your test assembly than it is to reach into a class through reflection. You get no compile-time checks that the method is still there with this, which makes it super-easy to break the code using nothing but easily reachable refactoring tools.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use an overload that lets you specify the `BindingFlags`, to specify `NonPublic`. For example:

```
    MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(TicketManager).GetMethod("Validate",
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
        null, new Type[] { typeof(TicketResponse) }, null);
```

However, in the context of testing, I wonder if this should either actually have a public API, or at least have an `internal` API (rather than `private`) and use `[InternalsVisibleTo(...)]` to let your test suite access it.

Comment: This does exactly what I needed. Thank you. The testing context is irrelevant here, I'm solely trying to achieve this as an example of using reflection and exactly why it is not recommended to do when testing your code.